# Algebra Cycles and functions

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone help to code this with tikz? I would like something that is more automatic and simpler.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=latex]
\node (a) {$1$};
\node (b) [below right of=a] {$2$};
\node (c) [below of=b] {$3$};
\node (d) [left of=c] {4};
\node (e) [above of=d] {5};
\draw (a) -- (b);
\draw (b) -- (c);
\draw (c) -- (d);
\draw (d) -- (e);
\draw (e) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe have a look into Ti*k*Z's `graphs` library:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph {
    subgraph C_n [n=5, clockwise, ->];
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, it is also possible to draw it with “`latex` arrows”:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\graph {
    subgraph C_n [n=5, clockwise, ->];
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]